# Client Script Assistance

Tags: javascript, api, netsuite

This might be an easy one but I need some assistance in NetSuite.  We have a an ITEM that if another item is pulled in with that particular ITEM (I will call it AB) but if they decide to pull CK with AB then it should trigger an alert message indicating that this cannot be done or just halt it there.

Hope this makes sense - thanks so much !

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do a Validate Line client side script.  You can do a 'return false' after displaying your message so that the user can change the item they are adding.